# Solving two second-order ODEs. Thx.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. $(x^2 -1)y''+4y'+2y=0\quad$
   This is one problem of the final exam of ODE in our school. It seems to have a solution except that by power series method. I tried every method but I failed.

2.$(x^3-1)y'' + (x-3)y'-y=0$

It has two solutions. $y_1=x-3$ and $y_2=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$ The first solution is easy, but it seems impossible to get the second solution by Liouville's method. How to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the first equation leads to a hypergeometric function

Comment: the solution of the second equation containes also a hypergeometric function

Comment: see here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2-1)*y''%2B4*y'%2B2*y%3D0

Comment: and here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E3-1)*y''%2B(x-3)*y'-y%3D0